# How to find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+n)}{2^n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Recently I'm studying about sequences and series(real analysis) and got stuck in the above problem. I tested for the convergence of the given series: $\sum u_n, $ where $u_n=\frac{\ln(1+n)}{2^n}$ and $u_{n+1}=\frac{\ln(2+n)}{2^{n+1}}$ . Thus, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}$$

$$=\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2+n)}{\ln(1+n)}\;\left(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\text{ form}\right)$$

$$=\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+n}{2+n},\text{ using L'Hospital's rule}$$

$$=\frac12\cdot1$$

$$=\frac12<1.$$

So by **D'Alembert's ratio test,** $\sum u_n$ converges.

But can't think of a way to evaluate the given infinite sum due to my little knowledge. Please suggest something regarding this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%281%2Bn%29%7D%7B2%5En%7D.) suggests there exists no closed form.

Comment: since the  its value expressed using Lerch transcendent function, I suspect that there is no  such  known closed form exist

Comment: Oh okay! Actually my text book only asked me to test for convergence of the series. But I, out of curiosity, tried to evaluate the sum based on my knowledge.. But failed! Then posted it here. BTW thanks both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the integral representation of the logarithm 
$$
\ln x = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t}  - e^{\, - \,x\,t} } \over t}dt} 
$$
we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & S = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\ln \left( {1 + k} \right)} \over {2^{\,\,k} }}}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t}  - e^{\, - \,\,t} e^{\, - \,k\,t} } \over {t\,2^{\,\,k} }}dt} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t} } \over {t\,}}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{1 \over {2^{\,\,k} }}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,k\,t} } \over {2^{\,\,k} }}} } \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t} } \over {t\,}}\left( {2 - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {e^{\, - \,k\left( {\,t + \ln 2} \right)} } } \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t} } \over {t\,}}\left( {2 - {1 \over {1 - e^{\, - \,\left( {\,t + \ln 2} \right)} }}} \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t} } \over {t\,}}\left( {2 - {{e^{\,\,\left( {\,t + \ln 2} \right)} } \over {e^{\,\,\left( {\,t + \ln 2} \right)}  - 1}}} \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t} } \over {t\,}}\left( {{{e^{\,\,\left( {\,t + \ln 2} \right)}  - 2} \over {e^{\,\,\left( {\,t + \ln 2} \right)}  - 1}}} \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{e^{\, - \,t} } \over {t\,}}\left( {{{e^{\,\,t}  - 1} \over {e^{\,\,t}  - 1/2}}} \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{{1 - e^{\, - \,t} } \over {t\left( {e^{\,\,t}  - 1/2} \right)}}dt}  \cr} 
$$

So this could be a first step to find some bounds on the value
of $S$ if not a closed form.